# How can I catch the resulting page of a post request using requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using Python with Requests and I'm trying to send data to a form for a website that shortens links. I want to store the link to their shortened link in a variable once I use requests.post.

I've read about status codes, but I don't quite know how to used them. Here's what the form for input looks like.

```
<form method="post" action="paste.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="12u">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name of paste" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="12u">
            <textarea name="paste" id="paste" placeholder="Paste contents"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="12u">
            <a type="submit" class="button form-button-submit">Upload</a>
            <a href="#" class="button button-alt form-button-reset">Undo</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's what I have so far.

```
def create_paste(url):
    title = 'title' # Define your title.
    paste = 'paste' # Define your paste content.

    try:
        durk = requests.post(url, data={'name': title, 'paste': paste})

        if durk.status_code == 302:
            print('Pasted!')
        else:
            print('Not pasted!')
    except:
        raise
```

How can I go about doing this? Thanks.

EDIT: Solved the problem by re-reading the Requests documentation. If I allow redirects and use r.url, I can show the paste link.

```
def derp():
    title = 'adsfjkl' # Define your title.
    paste = 'asdfasdhfasdflkjashdfkjasht' # Define your paste content.

    r = requests.post('http://website.com/paste.php', data={'name': title, 'paste': paste}, allow_redirects=True)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        print('Pasted! %s' % (r.url))
    else:
        print('Not pasted!')

    print r.url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to indeed use Requests.post and then pass this post result to [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and parse the result.

For instance:

```
import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

response = request.get('http://stackoverflow.com/') 
bs = BS(response.text)

//do some parsing using beautifulsoup to get the link
```

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't quite answer my question. A link to a web article or a short explanation on how I could use BS to catch the link would be awesome.

Comment: @Brandon Jackson: You have link to BS homepage in answer. There is no response HTML (with shortened link) in your question so we can't show you how to use BS to get exactly that link.

Comment: Solved the problem by re-reading the Requests documentation. If I allow redirects and use r.url, I can show the paste link. Thanks though!

Comment: I think `import response` should be `import requests`, the "response =" line should be `response = requests.get` and the "bs" line should be `bs = BS(response.text)`.  That said, it's far easier to make URL forwards with those services which provide an API (e.g. is.gd).